# What is a "scoring position" in baseball?

Tags: baseball, terminology, mlb

I heard the other day the commentator said a player is in "scoring position" after running to the second base.

What is a "scoring position" in baseball/MLB?

Comment: There is a wikipedia article on this term.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scoring_position

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is exactly being at second or third base. The point is that it is (usually) enough to hit a single to score a run by that player, which is not true for players at first base, or home.

Answer (score -2):

For a base hit it typically has to get out of the infield so a runner on second can score unless they had to hold for possible caught in the air.

On third runner can typically score on even a caught ball (sacrifice fly).

From first not going to score without error(s).